# Python: Variable is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python program that decides whether the value is odd or even. This is my  code:

```
def odd_or_even (a, b):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        b = "EVEN"
    else:
        b = "ODD"

    return x

odd_or_even (9, x)

print x
```

When I run it in Terminal, this is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py.py", line 9, in 
    odd_or_even (9, x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined

HELP PLEASE!?

Comment: Um... what is `x`? Why not just `return gobbledygook`? Why `x`?

Comment: @JoelCornett - lol at that comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return values through the parameter list like that in Python. Perhaps you wanted something like the following:

```
def odd_or_even (a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
        b = "EVEN"
    else:
        b = "ODD"

    return b

x = odd_or_even (9)

print x
```

In this example, the `odd_or_even` function returns a value (either `"EVEN"` or `"ODD"`) using the `return` statement. The caller assigns this return value to `x`, which is then printed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, 'b' is the result you want to return from your function.  In that case, you don't need to pass 'b' to the function.

Try this:

```
def odd_or_even (x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        result = x + " IS EVEN"
    else:
        result = x + " IS ODD"
    return result

print odd_or_even(9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you never declare what `x` is.

```
 def odd_or_even (a, b):
    if a % 2 == 0:
      b = "EVEN"
    else:
      b = "ODD"

     return x // <---- this function knows nothing about this value
```

You need to `return b` in the function and you don't need to pass in b:

```
def odd_or_even (a):
    if a % 2 == 0:
      b = "EVEN"
    else:
      b = "ODD"

     return b // <-- the function set b
```

When you call the function you don't need the variable

`x = odd_or_even(9)`

then just `print x`